# Eclipse editor crashes on javascript setter

Tags: javascript, eclipse, setter

If I define a Javascript setter in a file, like this one:

```
var SomeClass = {
    get prop() {
        "use strict";

        // code here
    },
    set prop(val) {
        "use strict";

         // code
    },
};
```

Eclipse will get an error every time I save the source file:

> Save Failed org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.StringLiteral
>   cannot be cast to
>   org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractVariableDeclaration

No problem if I remove the setter and I declare an explicit setter function, or I append it to the existing class using `Object.defineProperty`.

I have Eclipse Mars 4.5.1 for Linux.

Comment: seems like a bug from eclipse jsdt side. What version of eclipse you're using?

Comment: I'm using Mars 4.5.1 on Linux